# google maps, add new markers and delete old markers android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

in my application i get 25 markers from the webservice, and i add them to the map, then when user move the map i detect the center position and i get new 25 markers to add them in the map. the process must be:
1-get 25 markers from webservice
2-add the 25 markers to the map
3-when map move, detect the center position
4-get new 25 markers
5-add the new 25 markers to the map
6-delete the old 25 markers from the map
my problem is in number 6, how can i delete the 25 old markers after adding the 25 new markers.
i hope that i can find any helpful ideas, and thank you

Comment: here you find the code to add markers in my code, i didnt find how to share it here
the code works fine, i just want to add the new markers then delete the old ones
https://justpaste.it/5c4jr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `HashMap` class variable to hold information about the markers:

```
HashMap<Long, Marker> markerList = new HashMap<>();
```

(I assume bike.getId() returns a `long` type, but if you have used a different type you must change the definition of the `HashMap` and the following code to reflect that type.)

After the `for (Bikes bike : arrayList)` loop is run go through all the values in the markerList and remove the `Markers` that aren't in the arrayList.

```
private void addMarkers(){
    //set Markers of bikes list
    //First loop!!
    for (Bikes bike : arrayList){
        BitmapDescriptor pinMarker = null;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bike.getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(bike.getLongitude()));

        switch (bike.getBreakdown()){
            case "false":
                pinMarker = pinWork;
                break;
            case "true":
                pinMarker = pinMaintenance;
                break;
        }

        Marker marker = VelosMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(pinMarker)
            .zIndex(1));

        if(!markerList.containsKey(bike.getId())){
            Marker marker = map.addMarker(marker);

            //Add the marker to the marker list 
            markerList.put(bike.getId(), marker);

            HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put("id",bike.getId());
            data.put("imei",bike.getImei());
            data.put("inUse",bike.getInUse());
            data.put("breakdown",bike.getBreakdown());
            marker.setTag(data);
        }
    }

    // This will iterate through all the items in the new list ...
    //...and remove the markers that are not found in the new list
    // Second Loop!!
    Iterator<Long> it = markerList.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext();){
        Long key = it.next();
        if(!bikeContains(key)){
            Marker marker = markerList.remove(key);
            marker.remove();
        }
    }
}


private boolean bikeContains(Long id){
    for (Bikes bike : arrayList){
        Long bikeId = bike.getId();
        if(bikeId == id){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

The first time through `addMarkers()`:
The `markerList` is empty so in line `if(!markerList.containsKey(bike.getId())){` a new entry will be added every pass through the first loop `for (Bikes bike : arrayList){`. And the `Marker` will be added to the map. In the second loop `for (Long key : markerList.keySet()){` we iterate through the `HashMap` and if the `arrayList` does not contain the "key" then it is removed from the `markerList` and from the map. But, because this is the first time through, nothing will be removed.

The second time through the `addMarkers()` method different bike locations are present in the `arrayList` containing the `Bike` data which should have bikes with different "id"  values than the first time around--at least for some bikes.

This time when `if(!markerList.containsKey(bike.getId())){` is called some of the values for `bike.getId()` will still be in the `markerList` --> nothing is done! But, some `bike.getId()` values will not be in the list--> these will be add to the list and markers added to the map. This means you will have more than 25 markers and more than 25 elements in `markerList`.

In the second loop `for (Long key : markerList.keySet()){` a check is performed to see if the `arrayList` contains the keys from the `markerList`. If not in `arrayList` then that marker is removed from the `markerList` and the from the map.

Comment: the HashMap markerList every time get 25 new markers, and the arraylist get the same 25 new markers, so i get nothing deleted from the old markers. i think there is something missing here

Comment: @AymenMasmoudi :: Please look at the edited answer. I have added an "Explanation" of how the code works and a "Note"  describing what could be causing issues with your application. :: If your provide the code you are using in your tests, then I am certain that the issue can be resolved.

Comment: thank you for all this explanations, the only thing that i didnt understand is the for (Bikes bike : arrayList){ loop, if we suppose that markerList contain 27 markers and the arrayList contain 25 markers, this is mean that only 25 markers in the markerList will be checked and the result will e true, and the other 2 markers will not be checked so nothing will be deleted in the end. i hope if you can provide me the test project maybe i can understand more and thank you

Comment: @AymenMasmoudi :: My sincere apology. Take a look at the edited second loop. It now loops through the keys of the `HashMap` and removes those entries which are NOT in the `arrayList`. While retyping the example code I somehow used the wrong collection to loop through. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

@Barns thank you for your help, that loop doesn't work and i get this error java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry, so i change it with this loop and finnaly it works

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Marker>> iterator = markerList.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
        Map.Entry<String, Marker> entry = iterator.next();
        //Log.e("key", entry.getKey()+"");
        String bikeId = entry.getKey();
        int i = SearchBike(bikeId);
        //Log.e("i",i+"");
        if (i == 0) {
            Marker marker = entry.getValue();
            marker.remove();
            iterator.remove();
            markerList.remove(bikeId);
        }
    }
```

for SearchBike(bikeId) i create it because i can't use arrayList.contain() because the result is an object not a string

```
private int SearchBike(String id){
    int i = 0;

    for (Bikes bike : arrayList){
        if (bike.getId().equals(id)) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

so if i==0 that's mean the marker doesn't exist in the new list and should be deleted from the map

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake--Indeed I made a beginner's error by trying to modify the `HashMap` while looping through it. I have edited my answer with the suggestions you have made in order to provide "error"  free code--should someone want to use it in the future and for completeness. Thanks Again.

Comment: you'r welcome @Barns , but using while loop is not recommended because it will never stop looping, instead of using "for" loop, i just tested both of them and that's what i notes

Answer (score 0):

What you must do is, before adding the new markers, you must clear the map by calling mGoogleMap.clear() . And you have to do this every time before adding the new markers.

Comment: thats what i already do and it works fine, but the customer want to add the new markers then delete the old ones, here my code to add markers, i didn't find how to share it here
https://justpaste.it/5c4jr